# Bash script to read files with path having spaces

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

When I execute the command

`find /local/DW/nan-campaign-reports -name "*.txt"`

I get

```
/local/DW/nan-campaign-reports/Dec 2014/monthlyDump1.txt
/local/DW/nan-campaign-reports/Dec 2014/monthlyDump2.txt
```

But when I do

```
for i in `find /local/DW/nan-campaign-reports -name "*.txt"`
do
echo $i
done
```

I get

```
/local/DW/nan-campaign-reports/Dec
2014/monthlyDump1.txt

/local/DW/nan-campaign-reports/Dec
2014/monthlyDump2.txt
```

How do I get them is single line, 
having `echo "$(i)" or echo "$i"` did not help

Comment: it's because your for loop sees the filenames as two words

Comment: How do I ensure that it reads it as single line @Jasen

Comment: Please look at the usage of IFS The Internal Field Separator (IFS) that is used for word splitting after expansion a http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/%24IFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the input field separators to newline only will make for see each line as a new result not each word.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `find /local/DW/nan-campaign-reports -name "*.txt"`
do
echo $i
done
IFS=
```

Comment: Please be aware that this solution is broken because of pathname expansion. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer your question by a question:

> what do you want to do with each file?

If you only want to print the name of the files, then you don't need to parse the output of `find`. If you need to do something relatively simple with your files, you should definitely use the `-exec` switch. Now, if you really believe you need to parse the output of `find`, and if your `find` supports the `-print0` flag (GNU find does, but it's not POSIX), then:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
    echo "$i"
done < <(find /local/DW/nan-campaign-reports -name "*.txt" -print0)
```

This is the only robust way. The answers given, that propose to set `IFS=$'\n'` will break if a filename contains a newline, or, worse, will be subject to pathname expansion. Here's a demo:

```
$ touch ab.txt 'a[b].txt'
$ ls
ab.txt a[b].txt
$ # Surprising output:
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ for i in $(find -name '*.txt'); do echo "$i"; done
./ab.txt
./ab.txt
$ # Good output:
$ while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do echo "$i"; done < <(find -name "*.txt" -print0)
./ab.txt
./a[b].txt
```

The same thing happens with wildcards (try it yourself).

Comment: I wanted to read the content from the files and append to a file

Comment: @NandishA Then you don't need `find` at all: `cat *.txt >> file_to_append_to`.